# How do I evaluate this summation/series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1+r)^{-i} = \ ?$$

I have so far:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1+r)^{-i} = 1+ \frac{1}{1+r}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}+\ ... \ \frac{1}{(1+r)^\infty}$$

But I think it's supposed to be:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (1+r)^{-i} = \frac{1+r}{r} $$

Edit: I think the key is that I'm failing to understand how the denominators converge to r

Comment: Think about Geometric series.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series think you can find everything you need to solve it right here

Comment: taylor seies of $${1+x)}^{-1}=1+x+x^2....$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a geometric series if $r >0$ but an easy approach is

$$S=1+ \frac{1}{1+r}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^3}+\cdots $$

multiply by $1+r$ to give

$$(1+r)S = (1+r)+1+ \frac{1}{1+r}+\frac{1}{(1+r)^2}+\cdots$$

subtract to give

$$(1+r)S - S=1+r$$

and rearrange $$S=\frac{1+r}{r}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a geometric series, and can be evaluated using the formula
$$\sum_{n\ge0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x},\qquad{|x|<1}.$$
We see that your sum is given by plugging in $x=\frac{1}{1+r}$. Using this, we must make the assumption that $r$ satisfies $|1/(r+1)|<1$. Thus we have
$$\sum_{i\ge0}(1+r)^{-i}=\frac{1}{1-\tfrac{1}{1+r}}=\frac{r+1}{r}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use this "lemma":

> For $x$ with $|x|<1$ we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Using this lemma, your series is in fact equal to $$\frac{1}{1-(1+r)^{-1}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1+r}}=\frac{1}{\frac{r}{r+1}}=\frac{r+1}{r}$$

Now, here are $2$ proofs of the lemma:

---

#### $\text{Proof 1:}$

Let $$S=\sum_{i=o}^{\infty}x^i\text{ and observe that } x\cdot S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i-1=S-1$$ so $$x\cdot S=S-1\text{ which gives us }S=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

---

#### $\text{Proof 2:}$

Observe that $$\sum_{i=o}^{\infty}x^i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$